# Easy way to see my balance without having wallet synced

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, viewkey

just joined and have a question...

I started mining XMR when the new GUI was released and used the address generated to receive payment from pool. Unfortunately the mac I'm using is very old and it is taking forever to sync completely. So my question is, if there's a way to verify and make sure the coins are being sent to the address I used without syncing completely?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have tx hashes/id of tx that you expect (i.e., incoming txs) then you can check using this tool: http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html 
or this blockchain explorer: http://explore.moneroworld.com/

Just use your address and viewkey. No need to sync entire blockchain.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two ways to do this. First, you can check if your account received a payment by utilizing the viewkey. Second, you can check if your account received a payment by utilizing the private tx key. For the first method you'd need three things:

1. Your public address.
2. The transaction id / hash of your transaction.
3. Your *private* view key.

You can obtain the public address by typing `address` into the CLI. Similarly, you can optain the *private* viewkey by typing `viewkey` into the CLI. By contrast, for the GUI there is currently no option to obtain the viewkey. For the public address, however, you can go to the `Receive` page to obtain it. Subsequently, plug the aforementioned three things into [this](http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) tool. For every output the address owns it should show: `This address owns output x with pubkey: x for amount: x`. The sum should be equal to the amount sent.

For the second method you'd also need three things:

1. Your public address.
2. The transaction id / hash of your transaction.
3. The private tx key.

Only the *sender* is able to obtain the private tx key. Thus, if you didn't send the transaction yourself, you'd have to ask the sender to provide you with the private tx key. In the CLI you can obtain the private tx key by entering the `get_tx_key <transaction id/hash>` command. In the GUI you can obtain it by going to `Transaction History` and click on `details` of the relevant transaction. Subsequently, plug the aforementioned three things into [this](http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) tool. Note that you should change "Private Viewkey" to "Tx Private Key" The "result" is similar to the result for the private view key.

Given that you are mining on a pool and the pool operator will send out the payments, the first method is more convenient.